# Signed URL created by Google Cloud Storage Python library blob.generate_signed_url method gets "Access Denied" error

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

I am trying to create a signed URL for a private object stored in cloud storage.

The storage client is being created using a service account that has the Storage Admin role:

```
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('service.json')
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

url = blob.generate_signed_url(
    version="v4",
    # This URL is valid for 15 minutes
    expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
    # Allow GET requests using this URL.
    method="GET"
)
```

This generates a URL that when accessed via a browser gives this error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.</Details>
</Error>
```

What am I missing here? The service account has no problem interacting with the bucket or blob normally - I can download it/etc. It's just the Signed URL that doesn't work. I can make the object public and then download it - but that defeats the purpose of being able to generate a signed URL.

All of the other answers I've found seem to focus on issues using application default credentials or are very old examples from the v2 API.

Clearly there's something about how I'm using the service account - do I need to explicitly give it permissions on that particular object? Is the Storage Admin role not enough in this context?

Going crazy with this. Please help!

Comment: I just tested it using v4 just as you did (Storage Admin role on Service Account), it all worked just fine. So I gotta ask: how did you tested the service account has no prob. interacting with the object? The issue is very clear (storage.objects.get not provided to the account used), are you completely sure you are using the correct key.json file?

Comment: Also, what version of the Storage library are you using? latest one is 1.29.0